# How to update multiple divs having same class with different returned values on ajax success JQUERY

Tags: jquery, ajax

For instance there is a set of divs like

```
<div class="size"></div>
<div class="size"></div>
```

ajax post returns me this on success.

```
$.each (data, function (bb) { // data is returned
    console.log (data.newsize);
});

Object 
{name: "a2.jpg", newsize: "37.7 KB"}
{name: "a2.jpg", newsize: "37.7 KB"}
{name: "a1.jpg", newsize: "65.02 KB"}
{name: "a1.jpg", newsize: "65.02 KB"}
```

how do i append or insert values of `newsize` in divs with `size` class uniquely. it shows only last value of iteration in both divs. please advise best way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can target the index of the element in the returned object array with the occurrence of div elements and target them respectively.

```
var data = [{name: "a2.jpg", newsize: "37.7 KB"},
{name: "a2.jpg", newsize: "37.7 KB"},
{name: "a1.jpg", newsize: "65.02 KB"},
{name: "a1.jpg", newsize: "65.02 KB"}];

$.each(data,function(i){
  if($('div.size').eq(i).length) // safe check to see if the corresponding div at the index location does exist
  $('div.size').eq(i).text('size' + data[i].newsize);
});
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/1056u5vd/

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, actually two divs are created in page when 2 images were dropped in ajax post. so each image file returns two values `name` and `newsize` so ajax success returns me 4 indexes against 2 files. so only 2 divs should be updated with `newsize` values.

Comment: I'm sorry I didnt understand what you mean. Are you saying that the div should be updated with the unique newsize values ?

Comment: exactly...for two images there should be two `newsize` values in two divs that's already in page with class `size`